# How many different subsets of a $10$-element set are there where the subsets have at most $8$ elements?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How many different subsets of a $10$-element set are there where the subsets have at most $8$ elements?

How do I do this problem?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2294252/120540

Comment: How many subsets total or there?  How many subsets have nine or more elements? If you remove the subsets with nine or more elements, how many are left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of $9$-element subsets is $10\choose9$, and the number of $10$-element subsets is $10\choose10$.

So the required ans is $2^{10}$-$10\choose9$-$10\choose10$$=1024-10-1=1013$

Answer (score 0):

If order matters, what you are referring to is known as a permutation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

If order does not matter, it is a combination. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Through google, you can find numerous explanations of them.

Answer (score 0):

The [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) has $2^{10}$ elements. Then, the number of subsets with exactly $10$ elements would the set itself, in other words $\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}$ subsets. Then, the number of subsets with exactly $9$ elements would be all of the elements minus one arbitrary element, since there are $10$ elements we have $10$ subsets with this property, in other words $\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix}$ subsets. Hence, the amount of subsets with at most $8$ subsets would be:
$$2^{10} - 10 - 1 = 1013.$$

Answer (score 0):

If a set has $n$ elements and you need to count the number of subsets with exactly $m$ elements we reason ... there are $n$ possible elements we can choose from the main set to put in the subset; then from the remaining $n-1$ we can $n-1$ possible to also put in the set;  from the remaining $n-2$ we can choose any to also put in the set.  So in the end there were $n*(n-1)*(n-2)*.......*(n-m+1)$ ways to pick what elements to put in the subset. But *VERY IMPORTANT* those choices all place the elements in a particular order which is not relevent-- if we put apples and oranges into a shopping bag it doesn't matter if we put the apples in first or the oranges in first.  So for every subset with $m$ elements there are $m!$ ways to arrange them ($m$ choices for the first elemet, $m-1$ for the second, etc.) becauuse $n*..... *(n-m+1)$ has every possible order and order doesn't matter, we have $m!$ too many.  So the number of possible subsets with $m$ elements are:

$\frac {n*..... *(n-m+1)}{m!} =$

$\frac {n*(n-1)*....*(n-m+1)*(n-m)...*2*1}{(n-m)*......*2*1)*m!}=$

$ \frac {n!}{(n-m)!m!} = {n \choose m}$

The notation ${n \choose m}$ is defined as $ \frac {n!}{(n-m)!m!}$ is called "$n$ choose $m$" and it ***literally*** means the number of ways to choose $m$ elements for set of $n$ elements.  So *by definition* then number of subsets with $m$ elements from a master set of $n$ elements is ${n \choose m} =\frac {n!}{(n-m)!m!}$.

So the number of subsets with at most $8$ elements are: The number of subsets with 0 elements + the number of subsets with 1 element + the number of subsets with 2 elements + .... + the number of subsets with 8 elements or:

${10 \choose 0} + {10 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 2} + ...... + {10 \choose 8}$.

But that is a lot to calculate.  There is probably an easier way.

Let $T = \text{the total number of all subsets}$

Then the number of subsets with at most $8$ elements are $ T - \text{the number of sets with 9 or 10 elements} = T - {10 \choose 9} - {10 \choose 10}$.

${10 \choose 9} = \frac {10!}{9!*1!} = \frac {10*9*8*.....*1}{9*8*....*1} =10$.  That is not surprising as the number as to get an subset with $9$ elements we  have to remove an element, and there are $10$ elements to choose from.

${10 \choose 10} = \frac {10!}{10!0!} = \frac {10!}{10!*1} = 1$.  This is absolutely not surprising as the only subset with 10 elements has to be the set itself.

So the number of subsets with at most $8$ elements is $T - 11$.

But what is $T$?

If a set has $n$ elements, for each element you have a choose: either you put the element into a subset, or you don't put it into a subset.  So there are $2^n$ possible subsets you can make.

So $T = 2^{10} = 1024$ and $11 $ of them have $9$ or more elements.  So the number of sets with $8$ or fewer are $1024 -11 = 1013$.