# Partial set of total combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the formula for all combinations of a set, split into two sets.

For example, the total combinations for 10 choose (1 to 10) = 2^10 - 1 = 1023 combinations.

Is there a way to determine a partial set of the total combinations, as in:

10 choose (1 to 5)

without having to calculate the binomial coefficient 6 times in a row,

e.g. 10 choose 1 + 10 choose 2 + 10 choose 3 + 10 choose 4 + 10 choose 5

Comment: Powerset, or the set of all subsets of a set with n elements has $2^n$ elements.  (the set itself and the empty set are both subsets).

Comment: How do I calculate the number of elements in a subset? e.g. 10 choose (1 to 5)

Comment: Here is an old post with the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295069/how-many-different-subsets-of-a-10-element-set-are-there-where-the-subsets-hav?rq=1 but the answers are to simply add up the subsets or alternatively subtract the subsets not used from the total.  I am trying to figure out if there is a formula that doesn't require adding or subtracting the subsets individually.

Comment: You really must be using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for the example you have shown, as that covers almost half of the expansion you can use this $\dfrac{2^{10} + {{10}\choose{5}}}{2} -1$.